# Get data between two dates in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need help, When I select tomorrow date then only today's data got. How to handle it? I don't have set any date. I have only date in database not datetime.

```
private static DataTable getData(string table, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_Demo"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Entry_Datetime between '" + startDate + "' and '" + endDate + "'"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is view

```
<label for="startDate" style="color:mediumvioletred">From:</label>

            @Html.TextBox("startDate", DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), new { @class = "form-control date", type = "date" })

        <label for="endDate" style="color:mediumvioletred">To:</label>

            @Html.TextBox("endDate", DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), new { @class = "form-control date", type = "date" })


        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Download" />
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will fix your issue..

```
 string startDate = dtp_dfrom.Value.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD");
 string endDate = dtp_dto.Value.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD");       

 string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_Demo"].ConnectionString;
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
 {
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Entry_Datetime 
   between @startDate and @endDate"))
        {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Connection = con;
  da.SelectCommand = cmd;
  da.Fill(dt);
  return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have **startDate** set to eg 00:00:00 30/12/2019 and **endDate** as 00:00:00 31/12/2019. Try adding one day to **endDate** so that you'll have 00:00:00 1/01/2020 and you'll have results from 00:00:00 30/12/2019 to 23:59:59 31/12/2019

Comment: I have'nt set date on startDate or endDate.

Comment: In your view you set startDate and endDate to DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").  Try setting endDate to DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") to see if it works. Also check if you have any date in your database from that range

Comment: But, I select date my self. Suppose, I have data in date of 30/12/2019. If I select date 30/12/2019 to 30/12/2019 then data will not download. If I select date 30/12/2019 to 31/12/2019 then data downloaded.

Comment: You try to select date from 00:00:00 30/12/2019 to 00:00:00 30/12/2019 and it gives you 0 seconds between that dates. If you want to select dates from 00:00:00 30/12/2019 to 23:59:59 30/12/2019 then you need to select 31/12/2019 as endDate (so your range is 00:00:00 30/12/2019 to 23:59:59 30/12/2019 now). You can solve this by adding one day to your endDate.

Comment: Or in other words: when you set startDate and endDate to 30/12/2019 then BETWEEN in your sql statement works like: select * from table1 where Date > 30/12/2019 and Date < 30/12/2019 so you have 0 results as nothing is in this range